# ScrollViewer not showing C#

Tags: c#, xaml, controls, scrollviewer

I am new to C# and not fully understand ScrollViewer. Please see the code below and tell me why no Scroll bar becomes visible when below mentiond groupbox gets displayed on screen.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="5">
    <GroupBox Name="grpDetail"  Margin="5"  Height="Auto" Grid.Row="5" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <my2:ucDisbursmentDetail Grid.Row="5" x:Name="ucDisbursmentDetail" Visibility="Collapsed"></my2:ucDisbursmentDetail>
    </GroupBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: so where's the code?))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ScrollViewer` is simply bigger than it's content therefore it doesn't need to show the scrollbar. Just add some height to it

```
<ScrollViewer Height="300">
    ...
</ScrollViewer>
```